# Get a value from a dictionary given the key of a different field

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

I'm using the third-party library [SwiftAddressBook](https://github.com/SocialbitGmbH/SwiftAddressBook) to work with Contacts in my app. I want to iterate through contacts in my device and extract a few specific values. Namely the twitter and facebook usernames if they exist.

`SwiftAddressBook` has an object called `SwiftAddressBookPerson` which represents a single contact. And `SwiftAddressBookPerson` object has a property called `socialProfiles` which contains an array of dictionaries. Each dictionary contains info about available social media account such as the username, url etc. Printing the value of `socialProfiles` looks like this.

```
[
    SwiftAddressBook.MultivalueEntry<Swift.Dictionary<SwiftAddressBook.SwiftAddressBookSocialProfileProperty, Swift.String>>(value: [
    SwiftAddressBook.SwiftAddressBookSocialProfileProperty.url: "http://twitter.com/isuru", 
    SwiftAddressBook.SwiftAddressBookSocialProfileProperty.username: "isuru", 
    SwiftAddressBook.SwiftAddressBookSocialProfileProperty.service: "twitter"], 
    label: nil, id: 0),

    SwiftAddressBook.MultivalueEntry<Swift.Dictionary<SwiftAddressBook.SwiftAddressBookSocialProfileProperty, Swift.String>>(value: [
    SwiftAddressBook.SwiftAddressBookSocialProfileProperty.url: "http://www.facebook.com/isuru", 
    SwiftAddressBook.SwiftAddressBookSocialProfileProperty.username: "isuru", 
    SwiftAddressBook.SwiftAddressBookSocialProfileProperty.service: "facebook"], 
    label: Optional("facebook"), id: 1)
]
```

I cleaned it up a little by doing this `socialProfiles.map { $0.map { $0.value } }` which outputs the following.

```
[
    [
        SwiftAddressBook.SwiftAddressBookSocialProfileProperty.url: "http://twitter.com/isuru", 
        SwiftAddressBook.SwiftAddressBookSocialProfileProperty.username: "isuru", 
        SwiftAddressBook.SwiftAddressBookSocialProfileProperty.service: "twitter"
    ],
    [
        SwiftAddressBook.SwiftAddressBookSocialProfileProperty.url: "http://www.facebook.com/isuru", 
        SwiftAddressBook.SwiftAddressBookSocialProfileProperty.username: "isuru", 
        SwiftAddressBook.SwiftAddressBookSocialProfileProperty.service: "facebook"
    ]
]
```

What I want now is given the service's name (twitter, facebook), retrieve the username used for that service.

How do I parse through the dictionary and get the value of a different field?

Answer (score 0):

Given that this is an array, I'd use a `first { $0.service == serviceName }`.

Alternatively, you could loop over the entire array ahead of time to create a dictionary with key as serviceName, and value as the profile property. The advantage of this approach is subsequent lookups would be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

I have named your array of swift address book dictionaries, `profiles`. The forced unwrapping in the flatMap call is safe because both key and value are tested for non-nil in the previous filter call.

The result is a single dictionary containing username values for the services listed in your `interestingServices` array.

```
let service = SwiftAddressBook.SwiftAddressBookSocialProfileProperty.service
let username = SwiftAddressBook.SwiftAddressBookSocialProfileProperty.username

let interestingServices = ["facebook", "twitter"]
let usernames = profiles
  .filter {
    guard
      let service = $0[service],
      $0[username] != nil
    else {
      return false
    }
    return interestingServices.contains(service)
  }
  .flatMap { profile in
    return [profile[service]!, profile[username]!]
  }
```

[image]